# i have to compare mobile price from flipkart and amazon and present on html taking user input in it

Tags: python-3.x

print there difference in which I used dataframe I want to make HTML page in which we get user input and passed in python code and print which site has the best buy

```
    mobile_name=input('pls enter a mobile model: ')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='E:\\python\\geckodriver')
    driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/');
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search_box.send_keys(mobile_name)
    search_box.submit()
    mobile_url=driver.current_url
    containers = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class': '_1UoZlX'})
    l = len(containers)
    price = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class': '_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})

    fl_price=[]
    for i in range(1):
        pr1=(price[i].text)
        fl_price.append(pr1)

        fl_price1=[]

for i in fl_price: fl_price1.append(i.replace("₹","")) driver.get('https://www.amazon.in/'); search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('field-keywords') search_box.send_keys(mobile_name) search_box.submit() mobile_url=driver.current_url data=requests.get(mobile_url) page_soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser') containers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sg-col-inner") l = len(containers) price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("a-price-whole") am_price=[] for i in range(1): pr=(price[i].text) am_price.append(pr) Al_price1=[] for i in am_price: Al_price1.append(i.replace("₹|,","")) d = {'Model Name': [mobile_name],'Flipkart price':fl_price1, 'Amazon price':am_price} df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) df['Flipkart price'] = df['Flipkart price'].str.replace(',', '') df['Amazon price'] = df['Amazon price'].str.replace(',', '') df['Savings'] = df['Flipkart price'].astype(float) - df['Amazon price'].astype(float) df['Savings'] =df['Savings'].abs()
```

I want HTML page where it accepts user input passed on while submitting the made it should execute the file

Comment: this code has no error i just want html which connects  html to python

Comment: If you have knowledge python based frameworks, like flask and Django, it can be easily done using them.

Comment: you have to do this by using flask, django or cgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want suggestion,

To return HTML from python you suppose to go with framework.

since you are a beginner start to implement the same using [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_from_directory) a python based based micro framework.

or if your requirement is big then go with [`django`](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

if you only want to return serve HTML via python then go with [`CGI`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm)

Remember.. to use all these 3 you need server like apache or wsgi.
for CGI you can do the same with apache or with python server. for django, flask it will comes with testing server like `WSGI`